# How do I get the sum of a value in a given line in an R-dataframe with all following lines respectively?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
  area    peri
1 4990 2791.90
2 7002 3892.60
3 7558 3930.66
4 7352 3869.32
```

It is produced by this code:

```
myData=(rock[1:3,c("area","peri")])
print(myData)
```

For every line in the data, I want to add the `peri`-value of each following line respectively. How do I do this? In other words:

**Question**:
What code do I need to apply to `myData` in order to get this:

```
  area1  area2   periSUM
1  4990   7002   6684.5
2  4990   7558   6722.56
3  4990   7352   6661.22
4  7002   7558   7823.26
5  7002   7352   7761.92
6  7558   7352   7799.98
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a self join in SQL:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.area as area1, b.area as area2, a.peri + b.peri as peri 
       from myData a join myData b on b.rowid > a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  area1 area2    peri
1  4990  7002 6684.50
2  4990  7558 6722.56
3  4990  7352 6661.22
4  7002  7558 7823.26
5  7002  7352 7761.92
6  7558  7352 7799.98
```

### Note

The input used in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
  area    peri
1 4990 2791.90
2 7002 3892.60
3 7558 3930.66
4 7352 3869.32"

myData <- read.table(text = Lines)
```